# The query results cannot be enumerated more than once

Tags: c#, exception, linq-to-sql

Consider the following methods. I am getting exception as asked , while repeater binding.

Bindrepeater:

```
private void BindRepeater()
{
    var idx = ListingPager.CurrentIndex;
    int itemCount;
    var keyword = Keywords.Text.Trim();
    var location = Area.Text.Trim();
    var list = _listing.GetBusinessListings(location, keyword, idx, out itemCount);
    ListingPager.ItemCount = itemCount;
    BusinessListingsRepeater.DataSource = list.ToList(); // exception here
    BusinessListingsRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

GetBusinessListings:

```
public IEnumerable<Listing> GetBusinessListings(string location, string keyword, int index, out int itemcount)
{
    var skip = GetItemsToSkip(index);
    var result = CompiledQueries.GetActiveListings(Context);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
    {
      result= result.Where(c => c.Address.Contains(location));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
    {
        result = result.Where(c => c.RelatedKeywords.Contains(keyword) || c.Description.Contains(keyword));
    }
    var list = result;

    itemcount = list.Count();
    return result.Skip(skip).Take(10);

}
```

GetActiveListings :

```
/// <summary>
///   Returns user specific listing
/// </summary>
public static readonly Func<DataContext, IQueryable<Listing>> GetActiveListings =
    CompiledQuery.Compile((DataContext db)
                          => from l in db.GetTable<Listing>()
                             where l.IsActive 
                             select l);
```

Answer (score 6):

When you assign `itemcount` you are executing the query the first time. Why do you need this?
My suggestion would be not to retrieve the item count there and just

```
return result.Skip(skip).Take(10).ToList();
```

Basically you can't have both, fetch only the results you need and retrieve the total count in one query. You could use two seperate querys though.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to persist your results as a collection, not an `IQueryable`.

```
var list = result.ToArray();

itemcount = list.Length;
return list.Skip(skip).Take(10);
```

The above code may not be correct for paging. You likely will have to run the query twice.

Comment: Instead of retrieving 10 items from the database, this retrieves all items from the database only to discard most of them.

Comment: The OP's code uses `Queryable.Skip` and `Queryable.Take`, so the OP's code is designed to be that flexible, even if it doesn't work yet. It's only in your answer that it's changed to `Enumerable.Skip` and `Enumerable.Take`.