# LINQ : The query results cannot be enumerated more than once

Tags: c#, linq

This is my code

```
 searchDataContext db = new searchDataContext();

    var query = (from p in db.SearchFirst(city, area)
                select new
                {
                    ID = p.Id,
                    Address = p.address,
                    Level = p.agahilevel

                });
    int count =query.Count();

    // records
    var q = query.Skip(Convert.ToInt32(start)).Take(Convert.ToInt32(width));

    if (q.Count() > 0)
    {
        int index = 0;
        str += "[";
        foreach (var row in q)
        {
            if (index == 0)
```

I have an error in this code

```
The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.
```

please check that and answer me.

Comment: possible duplicates: [The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723555), [The query results cannot be enumerated more than once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611666)

Comment: walther,I try your answer befor.it's not work to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Materialize your query:

```
var addresses = (from p in db.SearchFirst(city, area)
                select new
                {
                    ID = p.Id,
                    Address = p.address,
                    Level = p.agahilevel

                })
                .Skip(Convert.ToInt32(start))
                .Take(Convert.ToInt32(width))
                .ToList();
```

Then use `Enumerable.Any` to check if it contains elements:

```
if(addresses.Any())
{
    int index = 0; // ...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You cannot use cached queries and iterate over them more than once...
Make a `List<T>` of it and try it again

```
var q = query.ToList(); // work on this
```

Answer (score 5):

If you add `.ToList()` to your query your problem will be solved