# Enumerating over Linq query results

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach, enumeration

I have some .NET 4.5 code:

```
var result = db.storedProcedure(param)
if (!result.Any()) { return; }
foreach (var entry in result)
{
    // Some code...
}
```

At the `foreach`, an exception is throw:

```
The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.
```

How can I check if `result` is empty? I've also tried `if (result.Count() == 0)` and that also throws the same exception at the `foreach` loop. I've also tried `foreach (var entry in result.ToList())` and that also throws the same exception.

I have tried following the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169920/linq-the-query-results-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-once) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723555/the-result-of-a-query-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-once), with no luck.

I've also tried:

```
var result = db.storedProcedure(param)
if (!result.Any()) { return; }
var resultList = result.ToList();
foreach (var entry in resultList) {}
```

And I still get the same exception at that `foreach` loop as well.

There must be some way to easily check if a Linq result set is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have code after the `foreach` that you don't want to run if there are no records? If not then the `if (!result.Any()) { return; }` is not doing anything usefull anyway.

Comment: @BenRobinson: Yes, that is correct. I didn't include that code here because I don't think it is relevant to this specific question.

Comment: @GrantWinney: The `var resultList = result.ToList()` comes after the `.Any()` check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put the result into a List before iterating:

```
var result = db.storedProcedure(param).ToList();
if (result.Count == 0) { return; }
```

Comment: This works, thank you. However, I'm curious then to why there exists the Linq `.Any()` method if all it does is throw an exception. What is the point of that method existing, and how would one use it properly without raising an exception?

Comment: @smoothgrips you can still use Any method after ToList, the problem  with your code is Any enumerates the result before the foreach and that's why you are getting the exception. normally this is not the case, you can enumerate a query as many times as you want. but this is just a special case.

Comment: Sleman22 I meant that to be towards the `smoothgrips` sorry I will edit

Comment: perhaps you should google the Linq Any method and understand there are plenty of awesome linq tutorials online as well `smoothgrips`

Comment: @smoothgrips and the advantage of Any is that it allows you to check whether the query has some result without enumerating all of them.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I have googled the Linq Any method and understand what its purpose is. However, none of the tutorials that I can find address this specific problem, of iterating over the results AFTER calling `.Any()`. All of the tutorials I have found stop after calling `.Any()`. In my question I included links to other solutions that I tried, so obviously I tried googling before posting this question.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you even to make that check at all? Your loop won't even run at all if there's nothing in `result`. Just have this:

```
var result = db.storedProcedure(param)
foreach (var entry in result)
{
    // Some code...
}

return;
```

Comment: In many cases you are definitely correct. However, there exists code before and after the loop that runs depending on if the results are empty or not. I didn't include that code because it's not relevant to the specific question.