# Speed up Linq to Sql with compiled queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have applied linq to sql in my project and it's taking  a lot of time so I made a search to make it speedy and i have searched and took a reference from [here](http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/LINQ/LINQ%20to%20SQL%20CompiledQuery.aspx)

And my .cs code is

```
public static Func<DataClassesDataContext, int, IQueryable<editor_j_inf>>
editordetail1 = CompiledQuery.Compile((DataClassesDataContext db, int a) =>
                 from p1 in db.editor_j_infs
                 where p1.ed_journal_id == a
                 orderby p1.editor_id descending
                 select p1);   //Its my precompile process

public void editordetail()
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var rr = editordetail1(db,Convert.ToInt32(Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["j_id"].Value)));
    if (rr.Count() != 0)
    {
        txt_jtitle.Text = rr.First().j_title;
        txtissn_p.Text = rr.First().issn_p;           
    }        
}
```

but the error is coming as [image]

Comment: i have uploaded an image

Comment: sorry I think my proxy blocks the image.

Comment: Look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611666/the-query-results-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-once

Comment: @daryal my error is "The query results cannot be enumerated more than once."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the line:

`editordetail1(db,Convert.ToInt32(Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["j_id"].Value)));`

is possible returning an **`IEnumerable<T>`**. And when you call `Count()` in `rr.Count()` then you have enumerated your results.

That's why when you are calling `First()` below, you are trying to enumerate second time.

```
txt_jtitle.Text = rr.First().j_title;
```

Try converting your return value from function: `editordetail1` to a List as:

```
var rr = editordetail1(db,Convert.ToInt32(Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["j_id"].Value)));
var rrList = rr.ToList();
```

And now use the `Count` property on List  and then call First()

```
if (rrList.Count() != 0) // use the List rrList
    {
        txt_jtitle.Text = rr.First().j_title; 
        txtissn_p.Text = rr.First().issn_p;           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the following lines:

```
var rr = editordetail1(db,Convert.ToInt32(Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["j_id"].Value)));
if (rr.Count() != 0)
```

to:

```
var rr = editordetail1.Invoke(db,Convert.ToInt32(Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["j_id"].Value))).FirstOrDefault();
if (rr != null)
```